# Can you describe a face color in terms of an inherited face color?

Tags: org-mode, faces, customize, colors

Specifically, I want tags in org mode to be a variant of the color of the corresponding heading (e.g. less saturated or lighter).

Each org mode heading level is a different color, so I can't just directly change the color for the org tag face.

[image: Screenshot of org customize options]

I can clearly inherit a variant of the size, but there doesn't seem to be any way to inherit a variant of the color. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a really nice idea.  I'd love to do this in my own org-mode.  Please do share if you figure out a way!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot set a face to always be a certain amount lighter or darker than the inherited face.

You can not customize a face based on context either.

If you would like org tags to change color based on their location in the org tree, you will need to use a custom font-lock keyword function that programmatically apply colors to org tags based on location.

See the `function` and `(matcher . facespec)` sections of this document specifically: 
[Search Based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html)