# Org-link font size in the heading

Tags: org-mode, faces

I often use org-links in headings, e.g.:

```
*** Heading [[foo]]
**** Subheading [[bar]]
```

And I use different font-sizes for different levels.

Now, I would like the face of the link to be of the same font-size as the heading's. Is that possible?

I tried using `:inherit` but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `org-link` face is set exclusively not in addition to other faces.

And there is only a fixed reference point for `:inherit`.

There would either

1. have to be a context sensitive `:inherit` or
2. different faces for the context, like with the `org-level` faces. There is `org-level-1`, `org-level-2` and so forth. But there are no separate faces for `org-link-level-1`, `org-link-level-2`

You could probably

> use a custom font-lock keyword function that programmatically applies colors to org tags based on location

as suggestet in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20875/can-you-describe-a-face-color-in-terms-of-an-inherited-face-color/20890#20890)

Comment: As it turned out the font-height inheritance in the headings is a planned feature that would not be added to Org-mode until version 9.5. Current version of Org-mode is 9.4.4.